# Why is my question about causation downvoted?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions, asking-questions, down-votes, bounty

I have [a question on the main site](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/112526/does-binge-watching-cause-sleep-problems) that asks for studies that give a causative connection between two events/situations. In my opinion, causal inference is a viable field of research. However, the question has two downvotes and in the comments someone says that I should not ask this kind of questions. I also placed a bounty on it but I think that I don’t get answers because people don’t want to answer downvoted questions. What should I do to remove the downvotes and get answers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why is my question about causation downvoted?

Well, the comments under your question explain the downvotes (causation is difficult to establish oftentimes), but you can also see that these views are not unanimously shared. I, for one, think that separation of correlation from causation is important and I, for whatever it is worth, have upvoted your Q.

Do not mind downvotes too much, though, they are just a nudge to improve your question. You can add more information from the linked paper, explaining the findings, especially what *'the connection'* between binge watching and sleep issues is that the authors, apparently, describe. Also explain to us why that is just 'a connection' and not causation. Your question is a bit short on background info and it appears a bit ill researched. Providing more info and framing the post a bit more in a scientific context can yield a more positive reception on our site.